# How to produce unique values from long strings to use as table keys?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlite

I want to use files paths as key in my database tables. But using long strings as keys is not an efficient approach.

So I thought of someway to reduce the size of path. [Object.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) looked great, specially when it returns an `int`.

```
var key = path.GetHashCode();
```

But it is written in the document:

> A hash code is intended for efficient insertion and lookup in
>   collections that are based on a hash table. A hash code is not a
>   permanent value. For this reason:
>
> - Do not serialize hash code values or store them in databases.
> - Do not use the hash code as the key to retrieve an object from a       keyed collection.

So how to shorten a path string to use as a table key in DataBase?

Comment: Why not just use a `Guid`?

Comment: What type of data is going into this table?  Does it need to have relationships to other tables?

Comment: @BenRobinson I'm using SQLite and it is not so fast. Other tables are also depend on a file path so I want to reduce times I access the database by using path as key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't.  You can use fairly long strings as keys for a lookup based structure without real problems.  The whole *design* of a hash based or sorted data structure is to avoid actually comparing a large number of objects when you are searching through the structure.

If you use something to "shorten" the string you have two options, assume that all of the shortened strings are actually unique, meaning that your code doesn't function properly if there is a collision, or keep track of the real string along with the shortened string and use the real string to deal with collisions.  The latter is exactly what a something like a `Dictionary` is already doing for all of its keys, and a database index is going to be doing something comparable, so you have no reason to re-implement it.

Comment: Thanks @Servy. I'll use paths as keys and see what comes in :) .. I see it is reasonable, since rows will only be some couple of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Create a surrogate key using an identity column. You can still index or put a unique constraint on the file path.